# Possible to do double hashing with React Router HashRouter?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

Im trying to make this

```
<Route
    exact
    path={"/" + myPath + "/:product"}
    render={(props) => {
        return (
            <ProductInFocus
                productFocus={this.props.productFocus}
                state={this.props.productFocusState}
                match={props.match}
            />
        )
    }}
/>
```

where myPath is something like root/**mobiles/** or root/**clothes** or to whatever category the product belongs.

Right now, url ends up like this: `http://localhost:3000/#/mobiles/example`

I would like for it to look something like this: `http://localhost:3000/#/mobiles/#/example`

Problem is, React Router HashRouter only creates hash (#) for the first path, not the dynamic parameter.

Anyone had this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Fixed @TPorter.

Answer (score 0):

React Router doesn't offer this capability. The hash (#) is a part of the URI Spec ([RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)), and is intended to identify one fragment of a URI. It doesn't make sense to have two in the URL, just like it wouldn't make sense to have two question marks (?) in a URL.

Comment: Is there any way, then, to enable refreshing of the page and get the desired page without doing SSR?

Comment: Maybe ask a new question if this answer isn't sufficient.